# How can we decompose generalization gap as done in the paper "Generalization in Deep Learning"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am reading a recent paper "[Generalization in Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05468)" and I am unable to understand a step. In this step, they first take neural network as a direct acyclic graph(DAG) and described output of neural network as follows,

[image]

and then they decomposed generalization gap as follows,

[image]

without any explanation. Here z is,

[image]

Can someone explain this or point me towards the right direction.